# Как выполнить привязку массива строк к ListView состоящему из RadioButton?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется вот такая разметка:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Variants}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="(???)" GroupName="Variants"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Используемый в привязке к `ItemSource` `Variants` - массив строк.
Не могу понять, что мне необходимо написать в контенте `RadioButton`(Там где сейчас три вопросительных знака).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RadioButton Content="{Binding}" GroupName="Variants"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо)........